# Редактировать файл excel на php

Tags: php, excel

Здравствуйте! Есть excel файл, в этом файле нужно изменить один столбец. С помощью PHPExcel получаю данные из этого столбца, изменяю эти данные и сейчас необходимо эти новые данные обратно поставить в этот столбец и сохранить файл. Как можно это сделать, или как можно получить номер ячейки excel средствами php.

Answer (score 2):

Порядок действий приблизительно такой:

1. Открываете файл для чтения, получаете необходимые данные, проводите необходимые рассчеты, получая новые значения.
2. Заносите в файл новые значения. Для доступа к отдельной ячейке можно использовать метод `setCellValue`.

`$xls->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue('A1', 'Hello world!')`

3. Открываете поток на запись, загружаете в него модифицированный файл, сохраняете файл с тем же именем, что и у исходного, затирая старую версию файла.